# Installing Dragula with Angular CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli, dragula

How is it possible to incorporate Dragula into an Angular 2 project with Angular CLI?

I have installed it with:

```
npm install ng2-dragula dragula --save
```

and added it to my `app.module` with:

```
import { DragulaModule, DragulaService }   from 'ng2-dragula';
```

However, I get the error:

> "Cannot find module 'ng2-dragula'

The methods I have found suggest adding it to `angular-cli-build.js`, but I cannot find a file with that name.

What is the step-by-step process to get a third party module like Dragula to play along with Angular CLI?

Answer (score 4):

To add dragula to your project add the css and js to angular-cli.json (note going up a directory for these two sections as they work from **src**)

```
  "styles": [
    "../node_modules/dragula/dist/dragula.css",
    "styles.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/dragula/dist/dragula.js"
  ]
```

..then add the ng2-dragula to the packages section

```
  "packages": [
    "node_modules/ng2-dragula"
  ]
```

In **app.module.ts** import the module and declare the service.

```
import { DragulaModule, DragulaService } from '../../node_modules/ng2-dragula/ng2-dragula';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    DragulaModule
  ],
  providers: [
    DragulaService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: Where is the packages section? can´t find in on angular-cli.json

Answer (score 1):

> However I get the error "Cannot find module 'ng2-dragula'. The
>   suggested methods I have found suggest adding it to
>   angular-cli-build.js, but I cannot find a file with that name.

Now there's only angular-cli.json. You can try adding it in **scripts** section.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#3rd-party-library-installation

Comment: It removed the compile warning. I don't have time to check functionality today, but as soon as I have I will mark this as correct, given that it works.

Answer (score 0):

As per [the instructions for Angular 2 Webpack](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula/wiki#angular2-webpack), the correct import statement in app.module should read:

```
import {DragulaService, Dragula} from 'ng2-dragula/ng2-dragula';
```